# I need see all doc in inside subCollection Orders

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
late Stream<QuerySnapshot> orderStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('customers')
      .doc()// 
      .collection('orders')
      .where('deliveryState', isEqualTo: 'يتم تجهيز الطلب')
      .snapshots()
```

// how to get all doc of Order  subCollection
// how to get

Answer (score 0):

Calling `doc()` without any value generates a new unique reference to an (initially non-existing) document. That non-existing document won't have an `orders` subcollection, so you get no results.

- If you want to get the `orders` of one specific customer, you'll need to specify the document ID for that customer in the call to `doc(...)`.
- If you want to get documents from all `orders` collections, you'll need to [use a collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query).

Comment: this way not solve this issue because some time I have random a lot of customers id ,

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, so let's do first things first. Does the explanation at the top of my answer on why your current call doesn't work make sense? And does it also make sense why you either need to identify under which parent document you want to read the `orders`, or use a collection group query? If so, what doesn't work about what you tried based on my answer? Was there an error message?